# Laravel The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have the next trouble
I have a form, and when I click to register button, show me the next:

"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

But my method is POST, this is my Route:

```
Route::post('/createpedido',[
'uses'=>'PedidosControlador@pedidoagregado',
'as'=>'Pedidos.pedidoagregado']);
```

And this is part of my blade

```
            <form method="post" action="{{route('Pedidos.pedidoagregado')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="row text-center">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                    <h2>Agregar Pedido</h2>
                    <h3>Cliente: {{$Clientes->nombreempresa}}</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Datos Pedido</h2>
                    <hr size="5" color="#FF0000" />
```

And this is my complete controller

```
   public function pedidoagregado(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'pedido' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'fechapedido' => 'required|date|max:255',
        'fechaentrega' => 'required|date|max:255',
        'tipopedido' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'observaciones' => 'required|email|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/createpedido')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $pedido = $request['pedido'];
    $fechapedido = $request['fechapedido'];
    $fechaentrega = $request['fechaentrega'];
    $tipopedido = $request['tipopedido'];
    $observaciones = $request['observaciones'];
    $idcliente = $request['idcliente'];

    $pedidos = new Pedidos();

    $pedidos->idcliente = $idcliente ;
    $pedidos->npedido = $pedido;
    $pedidos->fechapedido = $fechapedido;
    $pedidos->fechaentrega = $fechaentrega;
    $pedidos->tipopedido = $tipopedido;
    $pedidos->observacones = $observaciones;
    $pedidos->save();

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Pedido Agregado Correctamente');

    if(Auth::user()->userlevel == "admin"){
    return redirect()->to('administrador/');
    }

    if(Auth::user()->userlevel == "ventas"){
        return redirect()->to('ventas/');
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can we see your whole form? It might be an issue further down where you submit. Also, have you issued `composer dump`?

Comment: hello @Beto, have you tried closing the <form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I check your code, which you provided and everything is fine. I guess, there is a probability you make two `routes` one get the form and second for post route for posting your data to the server.

and perhaps by mistake, you give same alias to both routes.

You give method `post` so whether you give same alias it should work, perhaps you forget to close `form tag` or by mistake, you have another form inside your `form`.
Perhaps there is some issue with route cache.
so clear it with artisan command.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Perhaps This will work, there is some probability you did something wrong, so I suggest you recheck all part I included in the answer.